# Llamar a un método dentro de otro

Tags: java

Dentro de una misma clase quiero llamar a un método dentro de otro de la siguiente forma:

```
public boolean dos(int i){
   return false;
   }
public boolean uno(int i){
   return dos(int i);
   }
```

pero no funciona ¿Por qué?

Comment: Cuidado, tu `return dos(int i);` tiene un error sintáctico. La forma correcta es: `return dos(i);`.

Comment: *pero no funciona ¿Por qué?* Aunque el problema en este caso es obvio, es bueno desarollar la costumbre de ser mas específico. Por ejemplo, en este caso, seguro obtuvistes un mensaje de error. Es importante incluírlo en tu pregunta. Lo menciono para tus futuras preguntas.

Comment: @OscarGarcia para futuras ocasiones, por favor trata de publicar esto como respuesta y no como comentario. Revisar aquí: [¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/958/227)

Comment: @Luiggi: En este caso, ¿no aplicaría el punto #5 de tu respuesta en meta? Que sería comentar en la pregunta y votar para cerrarla, ¿o entendí mal?

Comment: @sstan yo creo que está en un área gris, para alguien experimentado puede ser un error tipográfico, para alguien que recién esté aprendiendo (sobretodo viniendo de otros lenguajes donde esto sí se necesita) necesita una explicación al respecto. Fuera de si la pregunta debería estar cerrada o no, pienso que la respuesta no debería estar como comentario, sino como respuesta.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza creo que la pregunta se podía responder como comentario (y opcionalmente cerrarla). Ni aporta nada nuevo a la comunidad (es poco probable que alguien encuentre la respuesta a un problema similar a éste usando algún buscador como google ni el buscador propio de stackoverflow) ni merece la pena la reputación por una respuesta tan obvia. Me da igual si otro usuario se la lleva aunque respondiera después de mí.

Comment: @OscarGarcia si revisas el enlace que pongo, hay un apartado explícito que trata sobre las respuestas en comentarios. En resumen, no apoya al sitio las respuestas en comentarios. El detalle está en dicha respuesta.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza a mí, al menos, me da vergüenza poner mi comentario como respuesta. Como moderador entiendo que me lo recrimines. Gracias igualmente.

Answer (score 6):

La forma correcta sería así:

```
public boolean dos(int i){
   return false;
}

public boolean uno(int i){
   return dos(i); // <-- Aquí tenías el error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quita la definición de tipo en la llamada: `dos(i)` en vez de `dos(int i)`